# Install pgAdmin on a remote server and configure without a desktop environment

Tags: postgresql, unix, debian, pgadmin-4

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on a remote Debian 8.1 minimal VM. I am attempting to install pgAdmin4 in server mode so that I am able to access remotely via the web. I have successfully installed pgAdmin4 within a python virtual environment, but an issue arises at one of the final steps of configuration:

`Starting pgAdmin 4. Please navigate to http://localhost:5050 in your browser.`

Since I do not have a desktop environment installed (nor do I intend on installing one), how can I complete configuration without using `localhost`? I have attempted to connect using the server's public IP (e.g. http://80.254.0.132:5050) but am not able to resolve.

I do not have a firewall at the VM or server/NAT level.

I have updated `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf` and added `host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0   md5` to the configuration.

I have updated `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` and changed `listen_addresses = '*'`.

My full steps involved in post-Debian installation (sans new users) looks like the following:

```
# Initial update.

apt-get install sudo
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install vim -y

# Postgres.
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -

# Install PostgreSQL.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev python-dev

# Set postgres password.
sudo -s
cd ~
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
\password postgres

# Allow remote connections.
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf
# host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0   md5
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
# listen_addresses = '*'
sudo service postgresql restart

# Python and pgAdmin.
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper

# Create the virtual environment and install pgAdmin.
virtualenv pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev libgmp3-dev
sudo pip install cryptography pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin3/pgadmin4/v1.1/pip/pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl
pip install pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl
cp ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
python  ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default pgAdmin4 runs on loopback adapter, to make it run on ethernet (eth0) you need to change some of configuration options.

> You need to add below config options,
>
> DEFAULT_SERVER = '0.0.0.0'
>
> in config_local.py (in "pgAdmin4" folder).
>
> If also want to change default port then also add
>
> DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 8081

Now restart pgAdmin4, Now try accessing pgAdmin4 using IP address you mentioned(eg, http://80.254.0.132:8081), It should work.

Comment: Perfect! It now works successfully. I appreciate your help.